# Can I hide Value in NumericUpDown control?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

Lets say we have `0` displayed in value field of the control and I want that if the value is `0` - display `string.Empty` (I know that the type of value is decimal and there can be no string inserted instead of decimals in it, but still... Maybe there is some formatting possible there?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: This is dependent on the current implementation of `NumericUpDown`.*

What you need to do is create a new control that inherits from `NumericUpDown` such that:

```
public partial class SpecialNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public SpecialNumericUpDown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        if (this.Value != 0)
        {
            base.UpdateEditText();
        }
        else
        {
            base.Controls[1].Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is only very limited support for changing the formatting.

I have not tried this myself. But you could create a subclass and override the `UpdateEditText` method to support your custom format. Something like this:

```
protected override void UpdateEditText()
{
   this.Text = Value.ToString(); // Insert your formatting here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return "0";
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals("0"))
            {
                base.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                base.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is calling the ResetText() method. You can restore the text changing the Value property.

Example code to hide text when NumericUpDown control is disabled, and restore it on enabled

```
private void NumericUpDown_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown.Enabled)
        {
            if (numericUpDown.Tag != null)
            {
                // Restore last value
                numericUpDown.Value = (decimal)numericUpDown.Tag;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Save last value
            numericUpDown.Tag = numericUpDown.Value;
            // Just to force value change 
            numericUpDown.Value = (numericUpDown.Value > numericUpDown.Minimum ? numericUpDown.Minimum : numericUpDown.Maximum);
            // Clear text
            numericUpDown.ResetText();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to hide the value from the user, you can make `ForeColor` the same as `BackColor` so the value inside `NumericUpDown` will be invisible to the user.